# How can I fire a second jQuery animation only after my first jQuery animation has finished?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this little animation activated by a link (`$control1`). When you click on that button the header goes down and the `.area2` div show with a fadeIn effect.

Is there a way to wait until the header goes down and then show the .area2 with the fadeIn effect? With this code both animations run at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#control1").toggle(
      function() { $("#header").animate({top:0}, 250); $(".area2").fadeIn(550);},
      function() { $("#header").animate({top:-82}, 250);$(".area2").fadeOut(550);}
  );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `complete` callback function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#control1").toggle(
      function() { $("#header").animate({top:0}, 250, function() {$(".area2").fadeIn(550);}); },
      function() { $("#header").animate({top:-82}, 250, function(){$(".area2").fadeOut(550);});}
  );
});
```

read the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you should just be able to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#control1").toggle(
    function() { $("#header").animate({top:0}, 250, function () {
       $(".area2").fadeIn(550); });
    },
    function() { $("#header").animate({top:-82}, 250, function () {
       $(".area2").fadeOut(550); });
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup: if you add a function as the last argument to your initial call to `animate` it’ll be fired when the animation has completed. You can put your second animation in this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#control1").toggle(
    function() {
      $("#header").animate({top:0}, 250, function(){
        $(".area2").fadeIn(550);
      });
    },

    function() {
      $("#header").animate({top:-82}, 250, function(){
        $(".area2").fadeOut(550);
      });
    }
  );
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/animate/